# Visited links on Meta are hard to see

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Maybe it is just my vision but I can't distinguish visited links in question/answer text from the surrounding text on Ubuntu Meta. I can see the links on the parent fine and I can see unvisited links here, but a visited link appears to be identical to regular text unless I move my mouse pointer over the link.